# Popup cannot be interacted with: "Daemons using outdated libraries" "Which services should be restarted?"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, package-management, daemon

The pop-up "Daemons using outdated libraries" "Which services should be restarted?" breaks my scripts as it cannot be interacted with, requiring me to interrupt. It happens when I use apt to install or update packages (in the script or directly in the shell). The script installs a bunch of software and packages. Here is an example:

[image]

I have tried this on multiple different shells and devices. My Ubuntu version is 20.04.

It does not register enter/return, and any keyboard input, such as the down arrow, does this:

[image]

I do not know why this is happening and I want to know how to prevent it from breaking like this (or just to prevent the popups entirely).

I installed iTerm but this did not change the behavior:
[image]

Here are some potentially relevant lines from the script (including some at the beginning that I added to attempt to resolve the issue):

```
echo '* libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections

# Set noninteractive frontend for apt-get to avoid prompts
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Define the file path
FILE_PATH="/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf"

# Check if the file exists
if [ -f "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
    # Use sed to replace 'i' with 'a' for the specific configuration
    sudo sed -i "s/\$nrconf{restart} = 'i';/\$nrconf{restart} = 'a';/g" "$FILE_PATH"
    
    echo "The file has been updated successfully."
else
    echo "The specified file does not exist."
fi

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive needrestart

sudo systemctl restart needrestart.service
echo '* libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo 'needrestart needrestart/restart-services boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections

# Update the package list and install dependencies
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -y

# Set timezone
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y tzdata && \
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

# Set environment variable for timezone
export TZ=America/New_York

# Attempt to install locales and generate en_US.UTF-8
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y locales && \
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

# Update packages, fix installations, install sudo, cleanup
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -f && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends sudo && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: What exact commands are you using that makes this dialogue box appear? You mention that you have a script; what does it do?

Comment: @Kusalananda It happens when I use apt to install or update packages. The script installs a bunch of software and packages.

Comment: This clarification should be part of the question, along with the exact commands that your script is using for package installation.

Comment: @Kusalananda The script is too long to include (bioinformatics pipeline setup). I will add the other information.

Comment: I never said to include the whole script. Only the bits relevant to you issue, which has to do with package installation.

Comment: @Kusalananda There are quite a lot of packages requiring many lines of code and configuration. Almost all ~600 lines are package installation (or other software downloads). Another reason why I am hesitant to try is that I am not sure what is relevant to the issue and what isn't. I will give it a try, though.

Comment: I suggest that you run your script with "set -x" enabled to track down exactly where what is causing this.

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried running the script with set -x, and the popups did not happen

Comment: @Kusalananda Actually, with set -x, it seems to prevent one of the popups but there is still one much later in the script that occurs.

Comment: `set -x` won’t change anything the script does, it will just show you the commands being run and allow you to determine exactly which lines are causing the dialogs to be shown. Is there anything directly involving `libc6` in your script? Why are you running `dpkg-reconfigure` manually? You only need to run `apt-get update` once, and you shouldn’t need to run `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, the script is not optimized and is still in development. I plan on cleaning it up afterward

Comment: @StephenKitt Probably there is nothing directly involving libc6 in the script

Answer (score 2):

The particular pop-up you mention is produced by `needrestart` (which I imagine you already know since your script configured it).

`needrestart` is invoked by hooks; the two relevant hooks here are its `apt` and `dpkg` hooks. The `apt` hook can be disabled temporarily by setting the `NEEDRESTART_SUSPEND` environment variable to a non-empty value. The `dpkg` hook isn’t configurable but it can be disabled by renaming it.

It’s worth noting too that the `NEEDRESTART_MODE` environment variable can be used to override the mode configuration setting (instead of modifying the configuration file).

I suggest the following approach:

1. Remove all the `needrestart` tweaks from your script.
2. Set `NEEDRESTART_SUSPEND` to a non-empty value and export it:

   ```
   export NEEDRESTART_SUSPEND=1
   ```
3. Set `NEEDRESTART_MODE` to either “automatic” or “list”:

   ```
   export NEEDRESTART_MODE=l
   ```
4. If the above isn’t sufficient, disable the `dpkg` hook; at the start of your script,

   ```
   [ -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/needrestart ] && mv /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/needrestart /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/needrestart.disabled
   ```

   and at the end (or in an exit trap),

   ```
   [ -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/needrestart.disabled ] && mv /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/needrestart.disabled /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/needrestart
   ```

If you want to restart daemons using outdated libraries, you might want to run `needrestart` explicitly at the end of your script.